# Django, the page does not display. must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: django, django-views

In a django project, when creating a contact page, I can't display the page using the DetailView class. Debug info shows that slug or pk is missing

here is my view:

```
class MyContactsView(DetailView):
model = Contacts
template_name = 'contacts/contact.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    """Generate the data to be displayed on the page."""
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    main_banner = MainBanner.objects.order_by('-id').last()
    context['main_banner'] = main_banner
    contacts = Contacts.objects.order_by('-id').last()
    context['contacts'] = contacts
    return context
```

URL

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.MyContactsView.as_view(), name='contacts'),
# path('', views.contact_page, name='contacts'),
```

]

Although in the url routes I did not specify additional parameters.

error message:
Generic detail view MyContactsView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Comment: Did you make the request with the pk of the object as a url parameter? DetailViews kinda require that or a slug as a url parameter. Slug only if the model declared a slug property.

Comment: No, I didn't use pk or slug in the query, you can see that in the url. I understood that it is better to use another display class, as DetailView requires pk or slug by default. But which class is better to use in this case, maybe TemplateView!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s what DetailViews require. They make get calls with the primary key of the object they ought to display. Look at the flow chart for the DetailView in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).

Comment: I had chosen TemplateView, now my app works correctly. Thank you very much!